# Performance problem MS SQL 2019 and OLEDB

Tags: sql-server, oledb, linked-server

I have tried to find answers for my problem, but until now without success.
We have migrated a customers DB-Server from MS SQL 2012 to MS SQL 2019.
There is a Linked Server, fetching data from an IBM/DB2 database.

With MS SQL Server 2012 it takes less than 1 second to get 10 rows from the Linked Server. With MS SQL Server 2019 ist takes 20 seconds or more!

If I increase the number of records to 100/1000 the result is displayed immediately, but the Query has Status "executing" for 20 Seconds.

Any help or hints in which direction I should is very much appreciated.

Best regards
Guenter

Comment: Are the SQL2012, SQL2019 and DB2 servers all on the same LAN? Or is the SQL2019 server now in a different network? I haven't had much experience with IBM's proprietary DB2 protocol, but if it's anything like TDS (Tabular Data Streams) used by Microsoft SQL and Oracle server's then (because it's very chatty) it's extremely sensitive to latency introduced by WAN and cellular networks.

Comment: SQL2012 and SQL2019 are in the same LAN, connection to DB2 goes through a VPN.
I am working for a hosting provider and in charge for SQL Server here. No full time job, doing it besides several other tasks.
When performance degraded after migrating, I was called in. I only know that SQL gets data from an ERP system running on DB2.
SQL2019 is a fresh installation, no in-place upgrade. I have made tests with the different compatibility levels, but it made no difference.
The test query is a simple SELECT TOP10 * from...

Comment: Have you configured the linked servers identically ie options for RPC, collation, Lazy schema etc

Comment: Is the ODBC driver the latest version?

Comment: There are multiple ways to make calls via linked servers. Please add to your question the exact SELECT statement you are using. It could be obfuscated.

Comment: stu: linked server configuration is identical, I have even checked if the creation scripts are identical

Charliface: on SQL2012 it is OLE DB Provider for DB2, Version 5.0, on SQL2019 it is Microsoft Host Integration Server 2016. Could this be the reason? I will add OLE DB Provider for DB2, Version 6.0

Yitzhak Khabinsky: 
SELECT top 10 *  FROM [Server].[Catalog].[Schema].[Table]

Thank you all for your replies and hints!

Comment: Hi all, I have found a solution but I don't like it. The reason for my performance issue is the version of DB2OLEDB.
I have copied the folder C:\Program Files\Microsoft OLE DB Provider for DB2 from SQL2012 to SQL2019 and now the query is as fast as before.
Are there any known incompatibilities between SQL2019 and the latest DB2OLEDB driver?
We do not have much customers using OLEDB by now, but the number could increase when migrating from SQL2014/16/17 to SQL2019/2022.
For the time being I will keep it as it is...

Answer (score 0):

The customer has confirmed, that after downgrading the OLEDB Driver for DB/2 v5.0 the performance is as good as on the old system.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55183

Comment: What did they downgrade to? That will be useful information as this post ages.